# Okta custom attributes on the user profile

Tags: okta, okta-api

I've added a custom profile attribute via the Okta admin screen called ABC_permissions.  This string value has a Json payload which is almost 1Meg in size.

When I call the API via the full url in a browser https......./users/test1@axxx.com I see the profile with the custom attribute listed in the browser.

Unfortunately, using the c# SDK, the profile object shows zero unmapped attributes so I am unable to retrieve the json payload on the server side code.  Any thoughts of what could be creating this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [current issue](https://github.com/okta/oktasdk-csharp/issues/34) with the C# SDK. Hopefully they will fix it soon.

Until then, you can call the API directly to get the user's entire profile, with all its custom attributes.